# How can I create an importable qml module with C++ code?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

I am trying to put together a QML module using C++. The book I am using only shows how to hook up the module via the `.pro` file. Since Qt Creator does not offer `qmake` as a build system option for this project type, I am forced to use cmake.

My project appears to build, but my `CustomObjectLib` module cannot be imported.

This is my custom object C++ code:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMOBJECT_H
#define CUSTOMOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QVariant>

class CustomObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    explicit CustomObject(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent)
    {}
    Q_INVOKABLE void setObject(QObject *object)
    {
        object->setProperty("text", QVariant("Clicked!"));
    }
};

#endif // CUSTOMOBJECT_H
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(QMLObjectInCPP VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appQMLObjectInCPP
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appQMLObjectInCPP
    URI QMLObjectInCPP
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

#
qt_add_qml_module(CustomObjectLib
    URI CustomObject
    VERSION 1.0
    SOURCES customobject.h customobject.cpp
)

set_target_properties(appQMLObjectInCPP PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appQMLObjectInCPP
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

install(TARGETS appQMLObjectInCPP
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

`Main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import CustomObjectLib

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CustomObject {
        id: customObject
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Click Me!")
        onClicked: {
            customObject.setObject(button)
        }
    }
}
```

In Qt Creator I get an error saying that the `CustomObjectLib` module cannot be found, and when I try to run the application I get the following output:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/QMLObjectInCPP/Main.qml:3:1: module "CustomObjectLib" is not installed
```

I have tried several variations on the name `CustomObjectLib`, but to no avail.

I'm reasonably sure I'm missing something simple, but thus far I cannot figure out what it might be.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You need to provide the required structure in order to install your module. Check this [example](https://github.com/omrdk/qopenai/blob/master/example/CMakeLists.txt) and follow the `add_subdirectory` cmd.

Comment: You can deploy CustomObject either (1) as part of your application, (2) or in a library project. I think you want the latter. You need to build and deploy a library project. On Windows, this will result in a *.dll and a qmldir file and, optionally, a qmltypes file deployed, typically in a `qml` subdirectory.

Comment: I really don't want to create a separate DLL. The point of this exercise was just to get beyond a section of a book that only provided its example as a qmake `.pro` file, which I was not able to use. The example that @dynerp pointed to didn't really help me much but it provided some clues to help me find another example that seems to have done the trick. I did indeed have to set up a separate sub-directory structure to get CMake to work.